# How to define a codeBase element depending on the platform (x86/x64)

Tags: .net, cross-platform, configuration-files

I have an issue with building(*)/testing a web application where I reference an assembly available in c:\program files on my workstation but in c:\program files (x86) on the build server. This assembly is "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.ASPNetHelper" (used a.o. for code coverage).

Locally, the path is "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.ASPNetHelper.dll".

On the Build Server, the path is "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.ASPNetHelper.dll".

As this assembly is not in the GAC, Visual Studio use a codeBase element in the web.config to define a binding

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.ASPNetHelper" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <codeBase version="10.0.0.0" href="file:///C:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%2010.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.ASPNetHelper.DLL"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

How could I manage this to make it work both locally and on the Build machine ? As far as I know, there is no way to either define variables or use environment variables in a config file...

V.